# Ipv4 Validation Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to write a function that validates an IPv4 address.

Everything appears ok but it doesn't appear to pick up the correct class.

My code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/felix001/X7EuJ/23/

```
<label for="input">IP</label>
<input type="text" name="input"  id="input" size="22" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" "whatmask_input" id="submit"  align="right" />
```

JavaScript:

```
function ipv4addr(x) {
    var REGEX = /^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$/;
    if ($x != $REGEX) {
        $("#input").addClass(".bad");
    }
    else {
        $("#input").addClass(".good");
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").click(ipv4addr("#input"));

});
```

Could anyone tell me the best way to troubleshoot this issue?

Thanks,

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your code in your question in addition to your fiddle link. Stack Overflow aims to be self-contained, and something unfortunate could happen to [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load your browser's development tools console (eg, in [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console)) while you have the fiddler page open.

The first error is:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $x
```

There is no need to prefix variable names with a $, `$foo` and `foo` are two different variable names. If you have `var foo`, then `foo` is the variable name.

And looking at the code, this probably doesn't do what you expect:

```
$("#submit").click(ipv4addr("#input"));
```

That would be the same as:

```
var result = ipv4addr("#input");
$("#submit").click(result);
```

That is, pass the return value of calling `ipv4addr` (which is always undefined) into the click method. You probably want to pass a function to get called on every click instead.

Comment: good shout about the variable name. However how do you pass the variable from the submit through to the variable ?

Comment: The missing step is getting the value out of the text box so that it can be passed into the validation function. You can use [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to get the value. Have a look at the examples on [.click(handler)](http://api.jquery.com/click/) to see how to make a function get called on a click event.

Answer (score 1):

Try this function:

```
function isDottedIPv4(s)
{
 var match = s.match(/^(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)$/);
 return match != null &&
        match[1] <= 255 && match[2] <= 255 &&
        match[3] <= 255 && match[4] <= 255;
}

isDottedIPv4("127.0.0.001") // true
isDottedIPv4("448.90210.0.65535") // false
isDottedIPv4("microsoft.com") // false
```

Comment: Class A addresses with a zero leading byte (`0.x.y.z`) are always invalid. Broadcast addresses (anything with `255`) may also be, depending on your definition of "invalid".